# how exim show password on log files

Tags: smtp, centos, exim, dovecot

I want to debug all auth session.

For example on **/var/log/exim/mainlog** display auth error like this;

> login authenticator failed for (xx) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect
>   authentication data (set_id=xxx)
>
> login authenticator failed for (xx) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect
>   authentication data (set_id=xxx)
>
> login authenticator failed for (xx) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect
>   authentication data (set_id=xxx)

but i want to display password too like this;

> login authenticator failed for (xx) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect
>   authentication data (set_id=xxx,**set_pwd=yyy**) login authenticator
>   failed for (xx) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect authentication data
>   (set_id=xxx,**set_pwd=yyy**) login authenticator failed for (xx)
>   [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=xxx,**set_pwd=yyy**)

I changed dovecot conf and added;

```
auth_verbose = yes
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
```

but /var/log/exim/mainlog still doesn't display password and /var/log/maillog doesn't give any information about smtp.

So, how can i catch auth error with cleared text password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution.

I changed dovecot.conf passdb options like;

```
passdb {
  driver = checkpassword
  args = /etc/dovecot/chk.sh
}
```

and write a bash script for write args on bash.log file.

like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1 username and $2 password" > /etc/dovecot/log.txt
```

Comment: Surely this won't work? The $1 that dovecot passes to the checkpassword script is the name of the "reply" program; the username and password are instead passed in via a file descriptor...

Answer (score 1):

Configuration options for Exim should be edited in `exim.conf`, as the dovecot.conf only affects how dovecot works. They are two separate programs.

As far as I know, there is no way to directly configure Exim to log the password in cleartext in the logfile. What you can do is add lines like the following

```
server_debug_print = "running smtp auth $1 $2"
```

under the correct authenticator in your `exim.conf` (or all of them) and then run `exim -d` which enables the debugging mode (but also makes exim run in the foreground with all debug output going to stdout).